# How to arc diff with only the current commit changes that are depend on other diffs?

Tags: git, arcanist

I created a stacked diff like this:

```
master - A - B - C
          \
           D
```

All the branches created by `arc feature branch_name`.
How do I change it to `A - B - C - D` while at the same time, D only shows it's own change?

Tried `Git rebase --onto C A`, but then D includes all the changes from B and C.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run

```
git rebase C D
```

That should be enough to get it like

```
a <- B <- C <- D
```

Comment: *(Just to be the pedantic one here, it won't be* `D` *of course, but a commit* `D'` *with the same set of changes* `D` *had)*